# CA0001: Error Running Code Analysis

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

When i am building my project for first time, facing below mentioned code analysis error. When i build project for second time, error resolved automatically.

CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis.

Required Attribute System.ComponentModel.LocalizableAttribute  on symbol message Could not be parsed. This attribute is required by the following rules Microsoft.CA1303, Microsoft.CA2204

For more information error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245246.aspx

Please help...

Comment: I suggest using a less glitching and more powerful analyzer PVS-Studio :). It easily finds bugs in the Microsoft code: https://www.viva64.com/en/inspections/#ID0EJGAC This shows that it is much better than visual studio analyzer.

Comment: @Andrey you may want to disclose your affiliation and mention that PVS-Studio is a paid solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster Visual Studio also is a paid solution. Note: How to use PVS-Studio free license: https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0457/

Comment: As an assumption - when you build project for second time nothing is changed in source files and project skipped from compilation? What will be with error if you run Rebuild, instead of Build?

Comment: Same error will appear again.